# Missing 1 required positional argument in python tests

Tags: python, testing, parameters, mocking

```
@patch("aioboto3.client")
@patch(“my_handler.send_batch", new_callable=truthy_async_mock)
@patch("my_handler.ConfigLoader.get_config")
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"STAGE": "Prod”})
@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_value", ["123", "456"])
def testThis(
        self,
        expected_value,
        sqs_mock,
        appconfig_mock,
        _mock_boto_client,
):
```

I am getting `missing 1 required positional argument _mock_boto_client`. I tried changing the order

```
@patch("aioboto3.client")
@patch(“my_handler.send_batch", new_callable=truthy_async_mock)
@patch("my_handler.ConfigLoader.get_config")
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"STAGE": "Prod”})
@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_value", ["123", "456"])
def testThis(
        self,
        sqs_mock,
        appconfig_mock,
        _mock_boto_client,
        expected_value,
)
```

Then getting `missing 1 required positional argument: 'expected_value'`. If I remove `expected_value` argument then everything is working fine. I am not sure what I am missing here. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The problem is that you are calling this function with too few arguments.  Show us the call to the function.

Comment: It's a test method. No one calling this explicitly.

Comment: Well, _something_ is clearly calling it.  Please show the full error traceback message.

Comment: @wraps(f)
[CPython37-test]     def _inner(*args, **kw):
[CPython37-test]         self._patch_dict()
[CPython37-test]         try:
[CPython37-test] >           return f(*args, **kw)
[CPython37-test] E           TypeError: testThis() missing 1 required positional argument: '_mock_boto_client'

Comment: That is a very odd error traceback message.  Where does `[CPython37-test]` come from?

Comment: ```@wraps(f) def _inner(*args, **kw): self._patch_dict()  try:  return f(*args, **kw)  E TypeError: testThis() missing 1 required positional argument: '_mock_boto_client'``` Updated it.